# Sort results by ranking

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to search for a keyword in Mongo collection but results not sorted as per their rank..so after finding match, I am sorting by textscore using the code below
In java code , I am writing

```
Aggregates.project(Projections.metaTextScore("textScore"))
Aggregates.sort(Sorts.metaTextScore("textScore"))
```

I am getting an error "pipeline requires text score metadata, but there is no text score available"

I have created a text index on the field.. appreciate if you can point me into right direction .

```
    public Document find(Map<String,String> params){    

    ProcessRequest request  = new ProcessRequest();
    request.parseSearch(params);
    MongoCollection<Document> mcollection = mconfig.getRecordCollection();
    long count  = mcollection.count(request.getFilter());
    logger.info("Count :"+count);
    AggregateIterable<Document> aggre = null;
    try{
     aggre = mcollection.aggregate(request.getQueryList());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    Document resultDoc = new Document();
    resultDoc.put("ResultCount", count);
    resultDoc.put("PageSize", request.getPageSize());
    resultDoc.put("ResultData",aggre);
    return resultDoc;

}
```

Thanks
SK

Comment: Would you able to show us the entire aggregation ?

Comment: @Veeram I have updated the questions with more details

Comment: don't see any text search code. Do you have more code ? what is your spring mongo jar version ?

Comment: spring mongo jar is 3.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have added textscore to projections, only textscore is getting displayed.. commenting out projections displayed all the fields

Comment: Just curious. Isn't this a different problem from what you had yesterday ? How did you fix the error mentioned in the question ?

Comment: @veeram I was getting the pipeline error because the search text value was null.. so I have put a condition to execute the Aggregates sort  Aggregates.sort(Sorts.metaTextScore("textScore")) if there is a search value